# blender 2.91.2 bevel node doesn't work properly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, bevel

bevel node doesn't work properly in rendered mode with cycles, it darken the edges rather than soften it
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to lower the radius in the bevel node.

If your cube is 2 units wide and the bevel radius is 1 m, it means the normals are interpolated right to the middle of each face, generating artifacts. Try the default (0.05).

Examples of the effect of the radius field :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]